# Python / Django from Terminal results in syntax error

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal

Hi I'm quite new to Programming so this is probably an easy question but I can't figure it out.

So I'm trying to build a simple website using Python and Django. In PyCharm I use the local Terminal and have a virtualenv set up. I can run commands such as `python manage.py runserver` and such. However when I start my normal Terminal window (not in PyCharm but the normal Mac Terminal app) and navigate to my project I can't execute any Django commands. I get the following error message:

```sh
  File "manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it a problem with the venv? I just want to use the normal Terminal application instead of the build-in one in PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks! However I found the actual reason why it didn't work. Had to activate the venv in the terminal. In the local terminal in PyCharm it's automatically activated.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.